# Accessing variables of an object slowing down program (C++)

Tags: c++, class, loops, optimization, vector

I am programming a simulation which loops through a vector. Within the code, it does an operation where it calculates delta x and y of 2 objects every iteration. The code I'm working on:

```
for(unsigned z = 0; z < creatures.size(); z++) {
    for(unsigned z2 = 0; z2 < creatures.size(); z2++) {
        if(z != z2) {
            int delta_x = creatures[z2].xpos - creatures[z].xpos;
            int delta_y = creatures[z2].ypos - creatures[z].ypos;
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the class:

```
class Creature {
    public:
        int xpos;
        int ypos;
        ...
};
```

Other code goes there but does not impact the performance as much. I notice that if I change the assignment of the deltas to a number or even a subtraction operation (such as z-z2 or something like that) it improves the "FPS" of the program from ~5 to ~7/8. Is there any way to speed up this operation?

Comment: Are you sure that this is the code that is having performance impact? It doesn't seem very costly to me.

Comment: Where are `creatures` defined?

Comment: @EdHeal

Vector:

`vector<Creature> creatures;`

The class itself is defined in a header file.

Comment: @BWG It definitely exists. Around a 3 FPS difference (which makes a difference when the program is running at ~4 vs ~7).

Comment: @DavidLougheed What is your other code doing that accessing a few things can change your fps by 3? Or are you on some super slow platform?

Comment: @BWG I'm on an oldish MBP and the program is iterating through a size 1000 vector and for each one iterating through the same vector again.

Comment: Use a profiler to identify the bottleneck of your program.

Comment: @DavidLougheed Man that is baffling to me. I can write code on my graphing calculator that runs faster than that. Granted, it is nowhere near as complex as a vector (just pointer arithmetic array), but it is still interesting.

Comment: @BWG I'm sure there are many other things wrong with my program! I just need to find it...

Comment: Are you timing code that's been built with compiler optimization options, or are you timing a debug build? STL container accesses in debug builds can often very slow due to a lot of validation of the iterators and/or accessors.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Welp. I didn't even know about the optimization options in compiling. That's helped out immensely thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Following may be faster

```
const std::size_t size = creatures.size();
for (unsigned z = 0; z + 1 < size; z++) {
    const int zx = creatures[z].xpos;
    const int zy = creatures[z].ypos;
    for (unsigned z2 = z + 1; z2 < size; z2++) {
            const int delta_x = creatures[z2].xpos - zx;
            const int delta_y = creatures[z2].ypos - zy;
    }
}
```

- move `creatures[z].xpos` outside of the loop.
- move `creatures.size()` outside of the loop.
- As the pair `{z, z2}` is symmetric to `{z2, z}`, group there jobs.

**EDIT**: `creatures.size()` moved outside of the loop (thanks to *shawn1874*)

Comment: Wow, can't believe I didn't think of that. Thank you so much! Got me about halfway there but I think I can implement this idea elsewhere to eke more performance out of this program. I wonder why accessing class variables takes up so much time...

Comment: Have you also tried using iterators or simply calling size only one time outside of the loop?  If accessing an attribute superfluously is causing performance issues, then certainly calling a member function over and over isn't going to help.  size_t theSize = creatures.size()